# How to compare differences in very large csv files

Tags: java, csv, large-files

I have to compare two csv files with a size of **2-3 GB** each, contained in Windows platform.

I've tried to put the first one in a HashMap to compare it with the second one, but the result (as expected) is a very high memory cosumption.

The target is to get the differences in another file.

The lines may appear in diffent order, and maybe missed also.

Any suggetions?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?  Do you just want to know if they are the same, or are you looking for something more like a diff tool?

Comment: More details would help.  Like are these files ordered so you can assume that they will have runs of identical lines (if so, you could iterate through them in parallel showing just diffs sort of like the diff command or any of it's graphical equivalents).

Comment: Have you tried any of the multitudinous "diff" tools?

Comment: (Of course, since you can open and read the files in Java it wouldn't be hard to simply do a line-by-line compare.  You do have to figure out a policy for mismatches, but depending on the type of mismatches expected this might be fairly trivial.)

Comment: You said they could be in different order, so is there a field that uniquely identifies a record? If not, do you just want to find how many records have same values? Does the difference reported have to be field specific or marking record enough?

Comment: There's a unique identifier in each record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you wish to do this in Java, via programming, the answers are different.

Are both of the files ordered?  If so, then you don't need to read in whole files, you simply start at the beginning of both files, and

1. If the entries match, advance the "current" line in both files.
2. If the entries don't match, determine which file's line would come first, display that line, and advance the current line *in that file*.

If you don't have ordered files, then perhaps you could order the files prior to the diff.  Again, since you need a low memory solution, don't read the entire file in to sort it.  Chop the file up into manageable chunks, and then sort each chunk.  Then use insertion sort to combine the chunks.

Answer (score 2):

The [unix command diff](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm) *can* work for exact matches.

You can also run it with the `-b` flag to ignore whitespace only differences.

Comment: Sorry, it's for windows platform

Comment: Diff exists for windows platforms, but you need to install it.  You can either install stand-alone executables (there was a port to windows of the standard GNU tools) or you can install cygwin, which also will provide a bash shell and a number of unix-compatiblity layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Edwin Buck, but I need to control the program under Java

Answer (score 2):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) as it comes with the fastest CSV parser for Java. You can process files as big as 100 GB without any issue and very quickly.

For comparison of large CSV files, I suggest you to use your own implementation of [RowProcessor](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/processor/RowProcessor.java) and wrap it in a [ConcurrentRowProcessor](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/processor/ConcurrentRowProcessor.java).

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: I am getting 421 Misdirect request while clicking on the demo link for the library https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you compare line by line and not to upload the entire file into memory. Or try uploading just a group of lines.

Answer (score 1):

There is a java library [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for parsing CSV files. Lazy loading of the file can be built. Check [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/incrementally-readstream-csv). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another similar post on Stack Overflow in which I have given the outline of a solution which requires only the smaller of the two files to be stored in memory:

[How to compare two large CSV files and get the difference file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120211/how-to-compare-two-large-csv-files-and-get-the-difference-file)

This is the general solution which doesn't require the files to be ordered, as you are stating in the question that order of lines may be different.

Anyway, even that can be avoided. I don't want to repeat the solution here, but the idea is to index one file and then walk through the other file. You can avoid storing entire smaller file in memory by only holding the hash table and location of each row in the index. In that way, you will have to touch the file many times on disk, but you won't have to keep it in memory.

Running time of the algorithm is O(N + M). Memory consumption is O(min(N, M)).